# Automatically convert acronyms to upper-case

Tags: feature-request

I'd like to request a feature, which is auto proper-case of acronyms to improve readability as well as meaning. This could also be extended to some common strings (*eg: i'm = I'm*) as well as capitalization of first letter in titles, but I think the acronyms part should be implemented by default, it's not complicated to do and it could include maybe the approved tags list.

Personally, I find pretty boring and tedious to have to edit posts because many SO users hate to use the *shift* key, so a proper case acronym *regex* would help greatly.

Comment: Do you have this list of acronyms?

Comment: @bluefeet: I see what you did there.

Comment: as I said in the question, it could be started by those acronyms included in the approved tags

Comment: "Personally, I find pretty boring and tedious to have to edit posts because many SO users hate to use the shift key" - Then don't.

Comment: sorry @StephanMuller, I thought the idea was to improve questions. My bad.

Comment: Automatically changing the title would be bad. Imagine a question about the `setTimeout` function for instance (with that function name in the title). *Fixing* that to `SetTimeout` would be wrong.

Comment: @Fabio I don't think that was the point of the comment from Stephan.  If you find it boring and tedious, there are plenty of other things to do on the site to keep it clean.

Comment: Indeed, that's what I meant. Didn't mean to come off rude, sorry.

Comment: There are *too many ways* this could backfire and go wrong. This is a *terrible* idea.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski, maybe I didn't explain myself, but I'm talking of a LIST of acronyms and its accepted case, I never said to randomly change things

Comment: @MartijnPieters please mention one

Comment: @Fabio: Discussing an algorithm to auto-uppercase acronyms for example. How are you going to include examples?

Comment: @Fabio I was reffering to this part: *as well as capitalization of first letter in titles*. Sorry if I misunderstood.

Comment: @MartijnPieters... inside code tags, obviously. Now, in a regular, non code paragraph is url the same as URL? html=HTML? MySQL=mysql? I know for a fact that proper case helps me to see it AND educates the user as well

Comment: @Fabio: 'proper' case for each of those is debatable. And bloody irritating if identifiers (that are not acronyms but should have been marked up with backticks) are auto-uppercased.

Comment: @Fabio: there are also words that happen to be both acronyms and have a different meaning when not capitalised. How are you proposing to detect the difference?

Comment: Well, I feel like talking to a wall.... this is the 4th time I have to mention a LIST. So, these words comes from a LIST. If it's not in a LIST nothing happens. If a word is debatable, you don't include it in a LIST. Anyways, scratch it, if something as simple an easy creates this controversy guess it's not a good idea

Comment: @Fabio could you provide an example of an acronym of what *would* be in this list?

Comment: HTML, URL, JRE, SQL, MySQL, BIOS, CGI, OOP, PDF, PNG, C+, CSS, SCSS, iOS, MVC and I could continue for days

Comment: @Fabio So all my pdf, html, cgi, css and png etc filenames have to have uppercase extensions? Filenames are allowed in regular paragraphs ... :(

Comment: well, I was pretty sure a decent coder could notice a difference between "this is a png file" and "my filename is image.png" but it seems not. Also, it seems the concept of ACRONYM got lost somewhere, how an ACRONYM is the same as a FILE EXTENSION is an absolute mystery to me. Maybe because English isn't my first (or even second or third) language, but I consider both things as completely different

Answer (score 4):

Many acronyms spell out an actual word when written out, in fact, some people don't even consider them to actually be acronyms when they don't spell a word.

If a feature like this gets implemented, prepare to have a lot of unexpected words to get capitalized when you don't want them to.

Comment: Best example of this I can think of: rest and [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer).

Comment: @AdamMaras and for that matter, SOAP too

Comment: Radar is the example that immediately came to my mind. Sonar is another good one. Literally no one capitalizes those. May not be very common on Stack Overflow, though…

Comment: @CodyGray those are known as *anacronyms*